# Подстановка переменной php в getElementById

Tags: php, javascript

Как правильно сделать подстановку id (берется из массива php `$IdLotItem`) в javascript при обращении к форме?
Пример:

```
document.getElementById("bid-form_$IdLotItem").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: @entithat благодарю не думал, что это так легко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно вставить `<?php echo $IdLotItem ?>`, получаем:

```
document.getElementById("bid-form_<?= $IdLotItem ?>").style.display = "none";
```

[Подробней о *php-тегах* в *html* файлах](https://www.ntchosting.com/encyclopedia/scripting-and-programming/php/php-in/)

Comment: спасибо за статью

Comment: @ЕвгенийПивоваров нужно __обязательно__ помнить, что подобные вставки могут открывать возможность для XSS атак. Данные необходимо экранировать перед вставкой

Comment: @tutankhamun благодарю за совет вас.

Comment: @ЕвгенийПивоваров [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/348558/#teg-ltscriptgt) на тему безопасности вставок в скрипты

Comment: @tutankhamun спасибо вам информацию, буду бдительным